# Forgery theorem: the Brownian motion stays close to any curve with positive probability

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

In a paper I am reading the authors claim that, if $B$ is a standard BM in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, then for any $\epsilon>0$
$$
\mathbb{P}(\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|B_t-f(t)|<\epsilon)>0.
$$
They do not give a proof for this result so I assume it is somewhat well-known, but I don't seem to be able to prove it. Looking online, I found that this is Exercise $1.8$ in the book of Morters and Peres (https://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/book.pdf). They give the following hint: *Given $f\in C[0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists n such that the function $g\in C[0,1]$, which agrees with $f$ on the dyadic points in $D_n$ and is linearly interpolated inbetween, satisfies $\sup|f(t)−g(t)|<\epsilon$. Then use Lévy’s construction of Brownian motion and the fact that normal distributions have full support to complete the proof.*

The hint however seems not to work. In facts, when I approximate $B$ with an appropriate piecewise linear process $S^{(n)}$ with nodes at $D_n$, I find that
$$
\forall \alpha>0\quad\forall \epsilon>0\quad \exists N\quad \forall n\geq N \quad \mathbb{P}(\sup_{[0,1]}|S^{(n)}_t-B_t|<\epsilon)>1-\alpha.
$$
Hence (assuming $f$ piecewise linear with nodes at $D_n$)
$$
\mathbb{P}(\sup_{[0,1]} |S^{(n)}_t-f(t)|<\epsilon)=:C(\epsilon,\alpha)>0.
$$
Combining I get
$$
\mathbb{P}(\sup_{[0,1]} |B_t-f(t)|<\epsilon)\geq C(\epsilon,\alpha)-\alpha,
$$
which however might very well be negative depending on the behavior of $C(\epsilon,\alpha)$.

Any idea on how to fix things?

Comment: Related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273230/exercise-on-a-hitting-time-for-a-brownian-motion?rq=1

Comment: I think I have a solution: see my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064700/sample-path-of-brownian-motion-within-epsilon-distance-of-continuous-function/4563178#4563178 (the accepted answer is wrong).

Comment: In Peres's answer he has some references for that result: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413986/the-wiener-measure-of-an-open-set/413993#413993

Comment: Doesn't Pinelis' answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413986/the-wiener-measure-of-an-open-set/413993#413993) also directly give the nonzero probability?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Wiener measure of an open set](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413986/the-wiener-measure-of-an-open-set)

Answer (score 3):

There was part of the hint that you ignored, namely using Levy's construction. To add some detail, the approximation of $S^{n}$ by BM is done recursively in each dyadic interval, rather than globally. For fixed $\epsilon>0$,  it suffices to prove that if   $n$ is large enough,  then for any real $r$ and any $a \in (-\epsilon/2, \epsilon/2)$, the event
$$A:=\{ |a+B(2^{-n})-r2^{-n}|<\epsilon/2  \quad \text{and} \quad \forall t \in [0,2^{-n}], \quad |a+B(t)-rt|<\epsilon,\},.$$
has positive probability. This follows easily from Levy's construction, or alternatively from the relation between Brownian motion and Brownian bridge.

See also the references in my previous answer  [The Wiener measure of an open set](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413986/the-wiener-measure-of-an-open-set/413993#413993)